# Use TypeConverter or break single class into multiple classes?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm trying to implement Room in an app that is already in production.

My question is how do I want to handle Entities with ArrayLists most efficiently in a Room Database?

I know my way around SQL and I'm pretty sure want is needed for 'observedDates' is a one to many relationship.
I'm just not sure what Room is doing in the background when you implement a TypeConverter. Is it just converting the the arraylist to a string and inserting it as a single field on the table? Or is doing more like creating a separate table with a joining table?
Would I want to use a TypeConverter for this field, or would it be better break it out into it's own class and do a one to many relationship?

```
@Entity(tableName = "spot_table")
public class Spot {

@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
    private UUID uuid;
    private int id;
    private int iNatId;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<LocalDate> observedDates;
    private LatLng latLng;
    private String image;
    private int fromEarlyMidLate;
    private int fromMonth;
    private int toEarlyMidLate;
    private int toMonth;
    private IconENUM iconENUM;
    private String iconName;
    private String notes;
    private String iNatURL;
....}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would I want to use a TypeConverter for this field, or would it be better break it out into it's own class and do a one to many relationship?
> In short there are proponents for both.

> My question is how do I want to handle Entities with ArrayLists most efficiently in a Room Database?

if efficiency is the criteria then I would suggest that utilising the relational aspect, i.e. a table for the related data, of the database is more efficient as you do not have to store additional data, bloat and that as SQLite is a relational database and additional that SQLite utilises C rather than Java is more efficient at storing and accessing the related data.

> I'm just not sure what Room is doing in the background when you implement a TypeConverter.

Room simply invokes the respective defined TypeConverter to save data and to retrieve the data.

SQLite, the actual database that Room uses, can store specific types of data per column. It can be

1. an INTEGER type,
2. a REAL type (decimal),
3. a TEXT type (String) or a BLOB type
4. a BLOB type (a stream of bytes, such as a ByteArray)
5. a NULL,
6. a NUMERIC type (which is a default type and is not supported by ROOM)

If an field is not one of these types then it needs to be converted to one of these types.

Obviously NULL is of no use as it is a single value.
INTEGER although  it can store very large values is very likely not usable without a suitable algorithm.
REAL, likewise would require such an algorithm.
So really to save such a field either requires conversion of the field, an object, into either a byte stream or a String.

Typically a JSON representation of the object is stored as it is a commonly used method of passing objects from one place to another.

A TypeConverter always requires a pair of converters (methods annotated with the `@TypeConverter` annotation ***note the singular***)

- one to convert the object to the single value that can be stored, and
- the other to return the object from the single value.

The class(es) in which the TypeConverters are defined have to be defined using the `@TypeConverters` annotation ***note the plural*** and have sufficient scope (at the `@Database` level provides the greatest scope).

Perhaps consider the following based upon your class (with many fields removed to simply matters):-

```
@Entity(tableName = "spot_table")
public class Spot {

   @PrimaryKey
   @NonNull
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private ArrayList<LocalDate> observedDates;


   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public ArrayList<LocalDate> getObservedDates() {
      return observedDates;
   }
   public void setObservedDates(ArrayList<LocalDate> observedDates) {
      this.observedDates = observedDates;
   }

   /* Useless Type Converters */
   @TypeConverter
   public String convertArrayListLocalDateToString(ArrayList<LocalDate> observedDates) {
      return "blah";
   }
   @TypeConverter
   public ArrayList<LocalDate> convertStringToArayListLocalDate(String retrievedFromDatabase) {
      return new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
   }
}
```

- note that the **TypeConverters** are:-

  - inlcuded in the Spot class (they could be elsewhere and typically are in a class of their own)
  - are **useless** as the data will always be stored as **blah** and retreived as an empty ArrayList.
  - highlighting that Room knows nothing about how the data is convertered just that it is.

Now consider the following `@Dao` annotated abstract class (could be an interface but abstract classed allow methods with bodies which can be useful):-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDAOs {

   @Insert
   abstract long insert(Spot spot);
   @Query("SELECT * FROM spot_table")
   abstract List<Spot> getAllSpots();
}
```

- i.e. nothing at all special a plain convenience insert and query

Lastly, in conjunction with the above, an `@Database` annotated class that also has the `@TypeConverters` annotation to define the Spot class as containing TypeConverters:-

```
@TypeConverters(value = {Spot.class})
@Database(entities = {Spot.class}, exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDAOs getAllDAOs();
}
```

After compiling the project then the generated java class AllDAOs_Impl (i.e. the `@Dao` annotated class suffixed with **_Impl**) includes the following code:-

```
final String _tmp = __spot.convertArrayListLocalDateToString(entity.getObservedDates());
....
_tmpObservedDates = __spot.convertStringToArayListLocalDate(_tmp);
```

- The first line in the code for inserting, the second line in the code that extracts the data.
- **i.e.** Room just includes the method calls, what they do (in this case a load of rubbish data wise) is not checked at any greater level other than the signature of the methods.

As you are saving a list of dates then you could simply save a CSV of the dates. So instead of the useless converters above you could instead have something like:-

```
@TypeConverter
public String convertLocalDateArrayToString(ArrayList<LocalDate> observedDates) {
    StringBuilder rv = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<observedDates.size(); i++) {
        if (i>0) rv.append(",");
        rv.append(observedDates.get(i).toString());
    }
    return rv.toString();
}
@TypeConverter
public ArrayList<LocalDate> convertStringToLocalDateArray(String databaseValue) {
    ArrayList<LocalDate> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] stringArray = databaseValue.split(",");
    for (String s: stringArray) {
        rv.add(LocalDate.parse(s,formatter));
    }
    return rv;
}
```

- this has minimal bloat i.e. just a comma between each item and would thus be more efficient than converting to a JSON representation using one of the available JSON libraries.
- where formatter is, for example, `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;`
- again showing that Room does not attempt to interrogate what the converter actually does.
- In this case the data in the database could, for example, be:-

[image]

The above data inserted using (and then extracted) using (with `@Database` modified to get a singleton of the database):-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
    dao = db.getAllDAOs();

    LocalDate ld01 = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate ld02 = LocalDate.now().plusDays(7);
    LocalDate ld03 = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(5);
    ArrayList<LocalDate> ald = new ArrayList<>();
    ald.add(ld01);

    Spot aSpot = new Spot();
    aSpot.setId(1);
    aSpot.setName("Test1");
    aSpot.setObservedDates(ald);
    dao.insert(aSpot);
    aSpot.setId(2);
    aSpot.setName("Test2");
    ald.add(ld02);
    dao.insert(aSpot);
    aSpot.setId(3);
    aSpot.setName("Test3");
    ald.add(ld03);
    dao.insert(aSpot);


    for(Spot s: dao.getAllSpots()) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (LocalDate  ld: s.getObservedDates()) {
            sb.append("\n\tDATE IS ").append(ld.format(Spot.formatter));
        }
        Log.d("SPOTINFO","Spot ID is" + s.getId() + " NAME is " + s.getName() + " There are " + s.getObservedDates().size() + " OBSERVED DATES. They are:-" + sb.toString());
    }
```

The log from the above includes:-

```
D/SPOTINFO: Spot ID is1 NAME is Test1 There are 1 OBSERVED DATES. They are:-
        DATE IS 2023-05-29
D/SPOTINFO: Spot ID is2 NAME is Test2 There are 2 OBSERVED DATES. They are:-
        DATE IS 2023-05-29
        DATE IS 2023-06-05
D/SPOTINFO: Spot ID is3 NAME is Test3 There are 3 OBSERVED DATES. They are:-
        DATE IS 2023-05-29
        DATE IS 2023-06-05
        DATE IS 2023-10-29
```

**The equivalent with TypeConverters. i.e. using a 1 to many relationship.

In this case a second table (**od**) will exist for storing the observed dates as a String (more efficient if long/Long but for brevity and ease of demo dates as string are easier to view).

So another class would be required e.g.

```
@Entity(
        tableName = "od",
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Spot.class,
                        parentColumns = {"id"},
                        childColumns = {"parentSpotId"},
                        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                )
        }
)
class ObservedDate {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long odId=null;
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    long parentSpotId;
    String date;

    public Long getOdId() {
        return odId;
    }

    public void setOdId(Long odId) {
        this.odId = odId;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public long getParentSpotId() {
        return parentSpotId;
    }

    public void setParentSpotId(long parentSpotId) {
        this.parentSpotId = parentSpotId;
    }
    ObservedDate(){}

    @Ignore
    ObservedDate(long parentSpotId, String date) {
        this.date = date;
        this.parentSpotId = parentSpotId;
    }
}
```

- Note that Foreign Keys are not compulsory. However, suggested as they enforce referential integrity.

  - Within Foreign Keys OnDelete and OnUpdate actions are optional. CASCADE helps to maintain referential integrity.

Now a DAO method will be required to insert ObservedDates so:-

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
abstract long insert(ObservedDate od);
```

As you would typically want to get a Spot with the child ObservedDates then a POJO that embeds the single parent (Spot) and relates the respective children (List of ObservedDates):-

```
class SpotWithObservedDates {
   @Embedded
   Spot spot;
   @Relation(
           entity = ObservedDate.class,
           parentColumn = "id",
           entityColumn = "parentSpotId"
   )
   List<ObservedDate> observedDateList;
}
```

The `@Embedded` and `@Relation` tell Room how to get the children for the adult. So all you need to get (in this case all Spots with the children) is a  Query that returns a list of the SpotWithObservedDates objects. So in the `@Dao`:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM spot_table")
abstract List<SpotWithObservedDates> getAllSpotsWithObservedDates();
```

- ***Note that the Spot class has not been changed so the TypeConverted list still remains*** You wouldn't do this if publishing the App. But for demonstration both methodologies present allows comparisons.

So the activity code could be extended to be :-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
    dao = db.getAllDAOs();

    LocalDate ld01 = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate ld02 = LocalDate.now().plusDays(7);
    LocalDate ld03 = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(5);
    ArrayList<LocalDate> ald = new ArrayList<>();
    ald.add(ld01);

    Spot aSpot = new Spot();
    aSpot.setId(1);
    aSpot.setName("Test1");
    aSpot.setObservedDates(ald);
    dao.insert(aSpot);
    aSpot.setId(2);
    aSpot.setName("Test2");
    ald.add(ld02);
    dao.insert(aSpot);
    aSpot.setId(3);
    aSpot.setName("Test3");
    ald.add(ld03);
    dao.insert(aSpot);


    /* Do the equivalent of the above but with the od table */
    /* note that the Spot rows already exist */
    dao.insert(new ObservedDate(1, ld01.format(Spot.formatter)));
    dao.insert(new ObservedDate(2,ld01.format(Spot.formatter)));
    dao.insert(new ObservedDate(2,ld02.format(Spot.formatter)));
    dao.insert(new ObservedDate(aSpot.getId(),ld01.format(Spot.formatter)));
    dao.insert(new ObservedDate(aSpot.getId(),ld02.format(Spot.formatter)));
    dao.insert(new ObservedDate(aSpot.getId(),ld03.format(Spot.formatter)));


    for(Spot s: dao.getAllSpots()) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (LocalDate  ld: s.getObservedDates()) {
            sb.append("\n\tDATE IS ").append(ld.format(Spot.formatter));
        }
        Log.d("SPOTINFO","Spot ID is" + s.getId() + " NAME is " + s.getName() + " There are " + s.getObservedDates().size() + " OBSERVED DATES. They are:-" + sb.toString());
    }

    for (SpotWithObservedDates swod: dao.getAllSpotsWithObservedDates()) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (ObservedDate od: swod.observedDateList) {
            sb.append("\n\tDATE IS ").append(od.getDate());
        }
        Log.d("SPOTINFO","Spot ID is" + swod.spot.getId() + " NAME is " + swod.spot.getName() + " There are " + swod.spot.getObservedDates().size() + " OBSERVED DATES. They are:-" + sb.toString());
    }
}
```

After running the above, then the database now has:-

[image]

- The highlighted data now superfluous as the of table contains:-

[image]

- Where odId is the unique row identifier, parentSpotId is the reference to the parent and date is the single date per an observation.

The Log now includes the additional messages:-

```
D/SPOTINFO: Spot ID is1 NAME is Test1 There are 1 OBSERVED DATES. They are:-
        DATE IS 2023-05-29
D/SPOTINFO: Spot ID is2 NAME is Test2 There are 2 OBSERVED DATES. They are:-
        DATE IS 2023-05-29
        DATE IS 2023-06-05
D/SPOTINFO: Spot ID is3 NAME is Test3 There are 3 OBSERVED DATES. They are:-
        DATE IS 2023-05-29
        DATE IS 2023-06-05
        DATE IS 2023-10-29
```

i.e. the end result is exactly the same